# Calulate average using a simple web form

Tags: javascript, average

I am having trouble getting the function to calculate the average.  It keeps returning NaN.

I am not sure why this is happening but I have put the code sample on jsfiddle for review.  Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6GQs/3/

```
  /*  This function calculates the sum and average for assignments that have been    completed.*/

function assignmentGrade () {
    var inputs = document.getElementById("assignments").getElementsByTagName("input");
    var i;
    var sum = 0;

    for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++) {    
        {
            sum += parseInt(inputs[i]);
        }   
    var average = sum / inputs.length;
    }

    document.getElementById('asumm').innerHTML = sum;   
}

var fieldset = document.getElementById('assignments');
var inputs = fieldset.getElementsByTagName('input');


for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++) 
{
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', assignmentGrade);
}
```

Comment: If there are less than seven numbers entered, should the average be calculated as if there are seven number, or only the number of values entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of issues...

First, you need to use the input's value instead of attempting to parse the input itself:

```
sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
```

Second, you're attempting to parse a few empty textboxes which is returning `NaN` and summing with `NaN` results in `NaN`. Check if the textbox is empty first:

```
if(inputs[i].value != '')
{
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
}
```

Another thing is that your average calculation is taking place on every iteration of the loop which isn't necessary:

```
for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++)
{
    if(inputs[i].value != '')
    {
       sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
    }
}   

var average = sum / inputs.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to indicate you want to use the input's *value*:

```
if(inputs[i].value != '')
    sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6GQs/4/

Note this will calculate the average based on the number of all the inputs, irrespective of whether they are empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

sum needed to be the input value which was giving the NaN and average needs to be computed outside the for loop, this should work:

```
function assignmentGrade ()
{
var inputs = document.getElementById("assignments").getElementsByTagName("input");
var i;
var sum = 0;

for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++) {    
    {
        if(inputs[i].value > 0) {
            sum += parseInt(inputs[i].value);
        }

    }   
}
var average = sum / inputs.length;

document.getElementById('asumm').innerHTML = average;   
}

var fieldset = document.getElementById('assignments');
var inputs = fieldset.getElementsByTagName('input');


for (var i = 0, num = inputs.length; i < num; i++) 
{
    inputs[i].addEventListener('change', assignmentGrade);
}
```